# How to update on union

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, union

I have a query that does a union on 2 tables. I want to update a column of the result.

something like this:

```
select * from(
    select a.*,'10' as srv from px_conversions_srv10 a 
    union all 
    select b.*,'12' as srv from px_conversions_srv12 b 
) as ff where ff.adv_transaction_id in(1333764016);
update ff SET ff.`status`=8;
```

Thanks

Comment: is the update really to have no conditions? Is so, you can just update all rows of the given trancation_id of both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is coming from two different tables you need to find out from which table the result comes. You can do this by adding a column to the query and later decide from the column value which table to update. You do this already with the srv column!

The update statement must be on the original table, since the union is only produced by the query. It is not a physical table in the database.

By extension of this logic, to answer the question in the title, you CANNOT execute an `UPDATE` on the result set of a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 1):

Just run two updates:

```
update px_conversions_srv10
    set status = 8
    where adv_transaction_id in (1333764016);

update px_conversions_srv12
    set status = 8
    where adv_transaction_id in (1333764016);
```

You can run these inside a single transaction if you want them to take effect at exactly the same time.

Note:  having multiple tables with the same columns is usually a sign of a poor database design.  There are reasons why this might be useful (say, the tables have different replication requirements or different security requirements).  But, in general, a single table is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a view table and then update it:

```
CREATE VIEW ff AS
select * from(
    select a.*,'10' as srv from px_conversions_srv10 a 
    union all 
    select b.*,'12' as srv from px_conversions_srv12 b 
) as ff where ff.adv_transaction_id in(1333764016);
update ff SET ff.`status`=8;
```